# Spring 3 + Hibernate: Should I use dirty checking, and how do I do so using annotation based transactions?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

First off, I'm new to Spring and I don't have my head quite wrapped around how it handles Hibernate transactions, so feel free to teach me a thing or two about it! :D

I'm writing an application with a standard Controller, Service, Data Access, and Persistence layer. So I have e.g. FileController, FileService, FileDao, with the SpringFramework handling Hibernate.

```
@Service
public class FileService {

    @Autowired
    FileDao fileDao;

    public FileService() {}

    @Transactional
    public File getRootFile() {
            return fileDao.getRootFile();
    }

    @Transactional
    public File getById(long id) {
            return fileDao.getById(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(File file) {
            fileDao.save(file);
    }
}
```

I'm also using the OpenSessionInView pattern with an OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.

I have two questions:

- Should I be using dirty checking with an open session in the View? Would that cause any changes the View could potentially make to the Model to be persisted?
- If dirty checking is a good idea, how do I do it? It seems that right now, I have to make a `save()` or `update()` call, otherwise dirty objects aren't persisted after my controller returns.

  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean optimistic locking, than have a look at Hibernate Documentation:
[Chapter 11.3. Optimistic concurrency control](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html)

Or JPA http://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_2_0_concurrency_and

The annotation you need is `@Version`

```
@Version
@Column(name = "version", nullable = false, length = 5)
public int getVersion() { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no, I'm not referring to locking mechanisms. I'm talking about dirty checking in Hibernate using the Spring framework.

Comment: @Brendan: what do you mean by dirty: an changed entity?

Comment: @Ralph: I'm only seeing it one place in the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-associations-working.

Comment: @Brendan: I see, but this is Hibernate basic functionality, you need nothing to do (and you can do nothing). Or did i missed something?

Comment: @Ralph: Then I need to know how to set up my (annotation based) transactions in Spring so that the commit will happen. Do I just put @Transactional on my controller methods, or do I need to explicitly flush the session somewhere?

Comment: @Brendan Put the @Transactional annotation to the mehtods that provide a transactional brace. You do not need to flush them explicite!. And you need to configure Spring `tx:annotation-driven`. *BTW In my personal opinion, uses AspectJ instread of Spring AOP Proxies/GCILib!*